# Cómo capturar valor de input con URL y mostrarlo en PHP?

Tags: php, url, youtube

Estoy editando una aplicación para descargar videos de YouTube y tengo el siguiente código donde quiero obtener la **URL** que se genera al presionar **DESCARGAR** y mostrarlo en un **IFRAME** para que, además de las opciones de descarga, también se pueda mostrar el video que se va a descargar.

```
<div style='width: 100%;margin-top: 100px;text-align: center'>
        <form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" action='index.php' onsubmit="prefixtrim()">
            <input id='video_url' style='width: 50%;height: 40px;color: #0000ff;font-size: 20px;' autocomplete="off" type='text' name='id' value='<?= $full_url ?>' placeholder="Pegue la URL del video de YouTube aquí" onclick="clearContent()" />
            <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='DESCARGAR' name='submit'>
        </form>
    </div>

    <iframe id="iframe" style="width: 560px; height: 315px"
        src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_REQUEST['submit'];  ?>"
        data-autoplay-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_REQUEST['submit']; ?>?autoplay=0"></iframe>
```

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas recargar la página para mostrar el contenido del `iframe` actualizado? Se puede actualizar el contenido sin tener que recargar la página. Asumo que tu página PHP es `index.php`, ¿Cierto? Con el código que estás mostrando, ¿qué problema tienes o sufres?.

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar pero ya lo resolvi, solo cambie este código: <?php echo $id; ?>

Comment: Te podrás imaginar que sin algo más de código era imposible saber de la existencia de esa variable. Por cierto, procura usar `<?= htmlspecialchars($id) ?>`.

Comment: Apenas estoy iniciando en el PHP, si quieres puedes ayudarme a arreglar cualquier error de codigo en mi aplicacion, seria de mucha ayuda :) https://github.com/JuarbeAbraham/JYTDownload